# Не заходит в breakpoint WinDBG

Tags: c#, отладка, breakpoint, windbg

Есть простенькая программа на C#:

```
namespace Stack_and_call_x86
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int result = Add(2,4);
        }

        static int Add (int a, int b)
        {
            int answer = a + b;
            return answer;
        }
    }
}
```

Написал и скомпилировал ее в MVS 2019. Пытаюсь отдебажить ее в WinDbg. Вроде все делаю правильно, прописал пути к символам, указываю место файла .cs, открываю в программе Launch executable. (Использую exeшник из папки Debug). Ставлю точку останова:

**bp Stack_and_call_x86!main**

Выдает следующее:

```
WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for Stack_and_call_x86.exe
Operation not supported by integrated managed debugging.
error at 'Stack_and_call_x86!main'
The breakpoint expression "Stack_and_call_x86!main" evaluates to the inline function.
Please use bm command to set breakpoints instead of bp.
```

Окей, ставлю bm:

**bm Stack_and_call_x86!main**

Ну вроде поставилась:

```
1: <MSIL:00ca0000         > @!"Stack_and_call_x86!Main"
```

Далее запускаю и получаю следующую ошибку:

```
ModLoad: 75e20000 75e99000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\ADVAPI32.dll
Breakpoint 1's offset expression evaluation failed.
Check for invalid symbols or bad syntax.
```

P.S.

Если открыть файл .cs через File - Open Source File, и там в коде поставить брейкпойнт, то он ставится, но при запуске такая ошибка:

```
Unable to insert breakpoint 0 at 00ca0001, Win32 error 0n998
    "Неверная попытка доступа к адресу памяти."
bp0 at 00ca0001 failed
```